# Django model edit form not showing up uploaded file and remove option

Tags: python, django

I have a model form with upload field,

**My form**

```
class AccountEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    telephone = forms.CharField(label=_('Telephone'), required=False,widget=forms.TextInput({'class': 'input-text input-box'}))
    cv = forms.FileField(required=True,widget=forms.FileInput({'class': 'input-text input-box'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('telephone','cv')
```

**My View**

```
class AccountEdit(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'base/account/edit.html'
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        profile = request.user.profile
        data = {
            'form': AccountEditForm(instance=profile)
        }
        return render(request,self.template_name,data)
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        profile = request.user.profile
        form = AccountEditForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Successfully updated your account.'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
        data = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request,self.template_name,data)
```

**My Template**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.telephone.label }}
    {{ form.telephone }}
    {% if form.telephone.errors %}
        {{ form.telephone.as_text }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.cv.label }}
    {{ form.cv }}
    {% if form.cv.errors %}
        {{ form.cv.errors.as_text }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

The problem is in edit form uploaded file is not getting displayed instead if I change some other field and submit it is throwing form error for **cv is required**

**Answer**

Now sure why but this works, **can any one make me understand this**

```
cv = forms.FileField(required=True)
```

Comment: Maybe the missing enctype="multipart/form-data" on the form could be the reason? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/ but yeah ihhcarus is right, I think you should use a FormView instead

Comment: It is there, upload is working unable to see the uploaded file but it is uploaded

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into extending [FormView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.9/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) instead of `TemplateView` in your views?

It handles all the necessary form instantiation for you so you don't need to create, populate and validate in your `get` and `post` functions. It would certainly make it easier for you to handle your use case.

As for your problem, you are probably forgetting to set the `files` parameter in your form instantiation in the `get` function. Please take a look at this from the Django documentation: [File Upload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads)

Can you try using the line below in your `get` function?

```
data = {
    'form': AccountEditForm(instance=profile, files=request.FILES)
}
```